Cross chain swap interoperability cross messaging using smart contract
Gm guys
I am working on a project where i need to be able to swap tokens from different Dex,
i want to send the detail of swaps from my EVM smart contract to solana so and the swap will be executed on solana , so solidity as a sender contract and solana as the receiver contract
what are the tools i can use for this task?
